# How to insert vspaces into scrlayer-notecolumn marginnote?

Tags: spacing, captions, scrlayer-notecolumn

Currently I am writing a book containing a load of images. As for captioning I emulate `tufe-latex`'s sidecaption functionality with `scrlayer-notecolumn`. The problem is that fullwidth-figures have vertically misaligned captions. They may overlap with the figure's content (see compiled MWE).

As for typical recommendations:

- It is not possible to switch to the `tufte-book` class or similar, because it conflicts with many other configurations I made for my book.
- My aim is to leave the code as is and just to change/redefine the commands for the reason that I'm not interested to convert all my `\caption` commands to possible alternatives like `\sidecaption`.

So my question is, whether it is possible to insert some vertical space in a note in scrlayer-notecolumn to bring the captions below the image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,DIV=calc,BCOR=15mm,blocks]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn,xparse,etoolbox} % for implementation
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % for implementation
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx} % for demonstration

% scrlayer-notecolumn for twoside=semi
\RedeclareNoteColumn[position=\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth+\marginparsep,width=\marginparwidth,font=\footnotesize]{marginpar}
% write something into margin (better marginpar)
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xmarginnote}{O{0pt} +m}{%
    \makenote[marginpar]{\hbox{}\vspace*{#1}\setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\noindent #2}%
}
% make env* ``fullwidth'' (tufte-like)
\AtEndPreamble{%
    \DeclareDocumentEnvironment{figure*}{o}{\begin{figure}[#1]\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}}
        {\end{adjustwidth}\end{figure}}
    \DeclareDocumentEnvironment{table*}{o}{\begin{table}[#1]\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}}
        {\end{adjustwidth}\end{table}}
}%

% redefine captions to fit into margin
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{subcaption}%
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}%
\DeclareCaptionFormat{sidenote}{\protect\xmarginnote{#1#2#3}}%
\DeclareCaptionFormat{sidenotebelow}{\protect\xmarginnote[\baselineskip]{#1#2#3}}%  the critical point
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecap}{parskip=0pt,skip=0pt,position=below,labelfont={footnotesize,bf},font=footnotesize,%
    singlelinecheck=off}%
\DeclareCaptionStyle{subsidecap}{format=plain,parskip=0pt,skip=0pt,position=below,labelfont={scriptsize,bf},labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,%
    font=scriptsize,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}%
\captionsetup[figure]{style=sidecap,format=sidenote}\captionsetup[table]{style=sidecap,format=sidenote}%
\captionsetup[figure*]{style=sidecap,format=sidenotebelow,skip=2\baselineskip}\captionsetup[table*]{style=sidecap,format=sidenote,skip=2\baselineskip}%
\captionsetup[sub]{style=subsidecap}%

\begin{document}
  This is the text with a \xmarginnote{See here.}.
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-A.pdf}
    \caption{Caption is working fine}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A.pdf}
        \caption{Subcaption great}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B.pdf}
        \caption{Subcaption great}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption is working fine}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure*}[h]
    \raggedleft
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-A.pdf}
    \caption{Caption is not working}
  \end{figure*}
  \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.35\paperwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A.pdf}
        \caption{Even a long subcaption is great}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.35\paperwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B.pdf}
        \caption{Even a long subcaption is (nearly) great}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption is not working}
  \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use an extra package to have `adjustwidth` instead of using `addmargin` or `addmargin*` environment provided by the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\vskip` instead of `\vspace*`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xmarginnote}{O{0pt} +m}{%
    \makenote[marginpar]{\vskip #1 \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\noindent #2}%
}
```

Results in:

[image]

As an alternative add `\par` after `\vspace*{…}`.