# How do I get `\captionof`s to be colored, when in `\makenote`s?

Tags: color, captions, koma-script, scrlayer-notecolumn

I can get my `\captionof`s to be blue.
I can get my `\makenote`s to be blue.
But it seems that no matter what I try I can never get `\captionof`s inside `\makenote`s to be blue.

#### Example

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}%
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}%

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn} %must be loaded ``Lastest''
\RedeclareNoteColumn[font = \color{blue}]{marginpar} %default

\DeclareCaptionFont{bluecaptionfont}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup{font={bluecaptionfont}, labelfont=bluecaptionfont}

\begin{document}

    here is the main text
    \makenote*{
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \captionof{figure}{This should be blue}
    }

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \captionof{figure}{Normal captionof's are blue}
    \end{minipage}

    \makenote*{
        Normal notes are blue
    }
\end{document}
```

Distantly related: [How to insert vspaces into scrlayer-notecolumn marginnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352052/how-to-insert-vspaces-into-scrlayer-notecolumn-marginnote)

#### Outputs

[image: screenshot of the output document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrlayer-notecolumn` v0.2.3085 from [the KOMA-Script source repository on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/koma-script/) does already support colors in note columns with LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX (but not with XeLaTeX). So the example from the question results in:

[image: result of scrlayer-notecolumn v0.2.3085]

Answer (score 3):

`\makenote*` redefines `\color` to do nothing and so the internal code of captions can't change the color. You can use another command but be aware that `\makenote*` has perhaps a reason for the redefinition: It is quite possible that the blue color leaks out.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}%
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}%

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn} %must be loaded ``Lastest''
\RedeclareNoteColumn[font = \color{blue}]{marginpar} %default

\let\mycolorcommand\color
\DeclareCaptionFont{bluecaptionfont}{\mycolorcommand{blue}}
\captionsetup{font={bluecaptionfont}, labelfont=bluecaptionfont}

\begin{document}

    here is the main text
    \makenote*{ 
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \captionof{figure}{This should be blue}
    }

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \tracingmacros=1 \captionof{figure}{Normal captionof's are blue}
    \end{minipage}

    \makenote*{
        Normal notes are blue
    }
\end{document}
```

A perhaps safer alternative is to locally redefine `\normalcolor`. Then caption can't reset the color and the color in the note wins:

```
\makenote*{ 
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \let\normalcolor\relax
    \captionof{figure}{This should be blue}
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks I've now submitted a bug report to Komascript -- if nothing else this should be documented more clearly.

Comment: The respond from Markus was (for anyone who is interested) :
_"This is intended due to the documented state of the package. It will not change unless implementation of a separate color stack for each note column.  Currently this is not on my todo list."_
  Which is I guess not unreasonable give that it is an experimental package.

Comment: saving the old color command indeed caused a bunch of weirdness, locally redefining `normalcolor` worked great though